# Appropriate synonym for "benefits"

Tags: single-word-requests

I've tried to write one sentence about local items. I want to change "benefits" since I already used it in another sentence. Also, I already used "advantages". Are there other words, instead of "benefits or advantages", which can be used in this sentence?

> Selling locally sourced items in a complex center has plenty of *benefits* since it helps the local commercial district.

Comment: A sentence about local items? Locally sourced products//complex center??

Comment: I'd simplify: "Selling locally sourced items helps that commercial district."

Comment: Actual synonyms are so rare you may as well assume they dont exist. But *already used it in another sentence* is a misguided justification for trying to find an alternative word. If it was the right word before, it should still be the right word when you want to refer to the same thing again later in your text. If you can't meaningfully explain why you want a different word, stick with your previous choice. Or go back and change it, if you discover a better term.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an exact synonym, but "upside" would convey the same idea in your sentence. [From M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upside):

> 2 a: a positive aspect
> b: PROMISE, POTENTIAL
> | a young star with lots of *upside*

Your sentence would then be:

> Selling locally sourced items in a complex center has plenty of upside since it helps the local commercial district.

Comment: Nice answer, but may I ask why you kept _2b_? (not criticizing, just wondering why it might be relevant)

Comment: @Heartspring My answer noted that "upside" wasn't an exact synonym, and I thought that 2b might be of interest to OP since it could be a valid reading in the revised sentence. I agree that 2a is closer to the original.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly obvious that helping the commercial district is a good thing. I don't think you need to specify that this is a "benefit":

> Selling locally sourced items in a complex center helps the local commercial district.

The long gerund phrase is a bit awkward; I might change it to:

> When you sell locally sourced items in a complex center, you help the local commercial district.